# Image not loading until I recompile my application (angular2, typescript, nodejs)

Tags: node.js, image, angular, typescript

I am trying to store an image and retrieve it in my application. Storing an image is perfectly working (storing in a specific server path) when it comes to retrieve, the image is not loading into browser until I recompile my `angular2` application which is done through `nodejs`. Below is the code to retrieve an image.

```
     <div class="row" *ngFor="let map of _selectedMaps;let index3 = index;trackBy:trackByIndex;" >
             <div class="col-md-1">{{map.id}}</div>
...
             <div class="col-md-1"><img class="media-icon" [attr.src]='selectedMapUrl(map)' />  
             <input type="file" id="fl{{index3}}" class="inputfile" (change)="mapChange($event, map)" placeholder="Upload map" accept=".png,.gif,.jpeg,.jpg"  />
             <label [attr.for]="'fl'+index3" >Load ...</label>
    </div>
```

.
    `selectedMapUrl(map)` is the method which is generating an URL (URL is generating correctly). I am attaching few screenshots of network and browser source storage.

[image: The ID 12600 doesn't contain image in Map column]
[image: Network response with 404 for image 12600.png even though the image is in path specified.]
[image: Browser storage doesn't contain the image]

I am just wondering whats going on, 12600.png will be loaded if I recompile my application.
I observed that whenever I recompile my application browser is reloading and webpack is reloaded.
Can anyone help me resolving.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you uploads an image it is getting upload in **project/src/assets/maps** but your application is fetching content from `dist` folder, that is why image is not appearing without compilation ..

because image went to the **project/src/assets/maps** folder of application not in the **project/dist/assets/maps** folder ( from where app is using content).

After compile image moved to the dist/assets/map so that is why image started appearing on application, Application is using dist folder's content after compilation. so that is why image appears after re-compile the application.

**So it is better to upload image file in dist/assets/map folder too along with project/src/assets/map folder.** This way image will start appearing without compilation.

```
var dir  = "src/assets/map";
var distdir ="dist/assets/map";

// image upload code for both locations
if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
                    fs.mkdirSync(dir,0775, function(err){
                        if(err){
                            fs.mkdirSync(dir);
                        }
                    });
                }
if (!fs.existsSync(distdir)){
           fs.mkdirSync(distdir,0775, function(err){
                        if(err){
                            fs.mkdirSync(distdir);
                        }
                    });
                }

fs.writeFile(dir+"/"+fileName, imageBuffer, {encoding:'utf8'}, function(err) {
                    if(err)
                        console.log(err);
                });

fs.writeFile(distdir+"/"+fileName, imageBuffer, {encoding:'utf8'}, function(err) {
                    if(err)
                        console.log(err);
                });
```

It also maintain image after compilation too.

Thank you!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160120/discussion-on-answer-by-deep-kakkar-image-not-loading-until-i-recompile-my-appli).